# Zimbra webmail advanced search

Tags: webmail, zimbra

My goal is to search my huge webmail with more then 2000 email with attachments.
It seems that Zimbra webmail search doesnt give results in GUI mode. Sometimes it works but shows only unread mail.

In programatic mode I didnt have luck.

My question is how to perform search in Zimbra webmail (Show some example)

My second question is if there is any material about zimbra webmail search (but not their official materials because they are not usefull to me)

Answer (score 0):

Well... I don't quite understand, what your problem exactly is. I find it quite easy to search in Zimbra. Just enter a term and Zimbra searches in the subject, mail text and addresses.

You can add wildcards (*) to search for partial words.

Besides this, you can add tags to search for specific things. For example, to search for all mails, that Mike sent to you, you'd search for "from:mike". (These tags are all quite well documented in Zimbra's online help)

The same query language is used programmatically (for example in SearchRequest-Api calls).

Comment: the problem is that it does not work for me and company i work for. i struggle with "search problem" for over a year. documentation is poor. ie.  is:read or is:flagged atributes dont produce any difference. The last thing that I had intention for is to induce surprise. I am looking for timbra clients with similar froblem to solve it.

Comment: Did you open a support or at least bug request for this?

Comment: i am not the person who is responsible for this, I am looking for workaraound.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. It should work (at lease it works perfect at my site)